# How can i extract the numeric part of a cell content in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on different set of data an would like to extract only numeric part of them from an excel sheet.
How could I do to extract only the numeric part please?

For example:

- "A51sd5dd5$1" I just need 51551
- "Bd203m01,02" I just need 2030102

I need of an Excel formula, or Vba function if you may help please.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions if you need this done with some simple code. Just replace all non digits or join digits in one go without iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome in the Forum! I think this is the kind of function you need to have.
I tested your examples and they are giving the right value in numeric of course.

Here is the function:

```
Function GetNumeric(CellRef As String)
Dim StringLength As Integer
StringLength = Len(CellRef) 'This is the Length of the CellRef entry

Dim n As Long
Dim sResult As String   'Store in a result variable the numeric characters

For n = 1 To StringLength
    'iterate through each character and test if it is numeric
    If IsNumeric(Mid(CellRef, n, 1)) Then sResult = sResult & Mid(CellRef, n, 1)
Next n

'Return your value
GetNumeric = sResult
End Function
```

I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 and `TEXTJOIN` function available to you then you can use below formula assuming your data is in cell `A1`.

`=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)+0,""))`

**EDIT:**

Following is a formula which you can use for Excel Versions later than 2007. If you have older than 2007 then `IFERROR` part needs to be re-worked.

`=NPV(-0.9,IFERROR(MID(A1,(LEN(A1)+1)-ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)*0.1,""))`

Comment: As long as the user is using 2016 and above version! And I need one that is standard to all versions

Comment: @Andry Thanks for the feedback. You can try the other formula which should work for most of the Excel Versions. Let me know if you have pre-2007 users.

Comment: this is interesting! Thank you for editing the answer and make it available for every available versions of Excel!